# Making a switch toggle darker using CSS

Tags: html, css, button, switch-statement, toggle

I have this basic switch toggle script which I found online and have implemented into my project. My sites background seems to be a bit too bright for the button to sit nicely without it being difficult too see, so my question is, how can I edit this switch toggle CSS code to make the it a little bit darker so I can use it on my site?

I'm only really worried about darkening the actual toggle button - that's the worst part and I have tried fiddling with the script but just cannot seem to find any part that changes the toggle?

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mam1yj1f/)

```
.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container > .switch {
  display: block;
  margin: 12px auto;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 56px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #03C;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, white 25px);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, white 25px);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, white 25px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, white 25px);
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity background;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity background;
  -o-transition-property: opacity background;
  transition-property: opacity background;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}
.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #47a8d8;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 40%, #f0f0f0);
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}
.switch-handle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, white);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, white);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, white);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, white);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 40px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-green > .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #4fb845;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `backgroud:#yourcolorcode` of class`.switch-label`

```
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity background;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity background;
  -o-transition-property: opacity background;
  transition-property: opacity background;
}
```

Also if you want to change the color of the circle of the radio button update the `.switch-handle` and `.switch-handle:before` classes

```
.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 40%, #000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 40%, #000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000 40%, #000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 40%, #000);
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}
.switch-handle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #000);
}
```

I hope this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/mam1yj1f/8/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer - sorry I wasn't clearer in my question, I was hoping to work out how to change the color of the white button that flips left and right. The actual toggle switch. Once I can darken that, I will also be able to darken the rest of the switch to match using your answer above.

Comment: for that you need to change gradient of .switch-handle and .switch-handle:before class  check https://jsfiddle.net/mam1yj1f/5/

Comment: Is that the correct link? Doesn't seem to be any changes?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for!!! Could you update your answer to show me what section needs editing and how to change the colors and I'll mark as correct!! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

add

```
.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 56px;
height: 20px;
padding: 3px;
background-color: #03C;
border-radius: 18px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: black;
}
```

to your CSS style, [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mam1yj1f/9/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am looking to update the white round toggle as well? Any idea's how that might be done?

Comment: updated my answer, you can change the rounded colour by changing the background-colour of .switch class, Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the switch label color as follows:

```
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: magenta;
  ....
}
```

P.D. I used magenta color just for making the example

Comment: Would this darken the actual toggle itself or just the on/off background colors?

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit the .switch-handle and .switch-handle:before.

This makes it darker, you just need to fiddle about the background colours to get what you want.

```
.switch-handle::before {

content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -6px 0px 0px -6px;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
/* change these!*/background: #F9F9F9 linear-gradient(to bottom, #A8A8A8, #959595) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) inset;

}

.switch-handle {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 4px;
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
/* change these!*/background: #FFF linear-gradient(to bottom, #CCC 40%, #F0F0F0) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
transition: left 0.15s ease-out 0s;
}
```